# Mongo limit return

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I must be doing this wrong. When fetching data from mongodb with mongod (node.js) I have implemented pagination using skip and limit.

```js
    const query = {};
    query.page  = Number(request.query.page) || 0;
    query.limit = Number(request.query.limit) || 36;
    query.skip  = query.page > 0 ? ((query.page - 1) * query.limit) : 0;
    query.query = null;



                db.collection('product').find( query.query , null, {
                    skip: query.skip,
                    limit: query.limit
                // sort etc
                }, (err, data) => {
                    if(err) {
                        return reply(Boom.internal('Internal DB error', err));        
                    } else {
                        return reply( data.toArray() )         
                    }
                });
```

When I visit my API at:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/products?page=700&limit=7
```

7 items are returned to me.... yet

```
http://localhost:3000/api/products?page=700&limit=36
```

Returns no items.... Surely it should return those 7 which exist? Any advice greatly appreciated.

** Edit - updated code to show query... this is all being used in a hapi app. I've stripped out all the handler stuff etc. for brevity.

** Edit - please see Thomas's

"page=700&limit=7 is equivalent to the indices 4900 .. 4906 while page=700&limit=36 would be the items 25200 .. 25235 which don't seem to exist. You may try to fetch page=136&limit=36"

basically - the number of pages is based on the limit... I had pushed myself out of range.

```
query.skip  = query.page > 0 ? ((query.page - 1) * query.limit) : 0;
```

...I should read my code...

Comment: You're hitting localhost on a different port. Maybe this makes a difference?

Comment: Sorry Mike C - that was a typo. I had changed the url of the test site to localhost

Comment: You're not sending `skip` in your request. Rather, you send `page`. Is it translated to `skip` behind the scenes or it's just an oversight? Show more code. As it is, this indeed is inexplicable.

Comment: `page=700&limit=7` is equivalient to the indices `4900 .. 4906` while `page=700&limit=36` would be the items `25200 .. 25235` wich don't seem to exist. You may try to fetch `page=136&limit=36`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks - have updated code.

Comment: @Rob: well, see Thomas' comment then. He got it.

Comment: @Thomas thanks! that makes absolutely perfect sense... the number of pages is directly related to the limit.  page=700&limit=36 throws it out of range. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Rob, you should further sanitize the inputs. `query.page = Math.max(1, 0|request.query.page);` and `query.limit = Math.max(1, Math.min(50, 0|request.query.limit));` because even a page `0` would lead to a negative index, or how about `page=0&limit=Infinity`

Comment: @Thomas - thanks. I'm checking with Joi, and have put a max / min on.